# Cosmos DB simple ID field for end user

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is it possible to include a user friendly ID field into cosmos db documents? This doesn't need to override the default id field that generates when adding a document but can be a custom one that is simple for an end user to know and search for.

Example document, the ref field is what I want to generate as a simple human readable identifier.

```
{
    "id": "57275754475457-5445444-44420478",
    "ref": "45H7GI",
    "userId": "48412",
    "whenCreated": "D2021-11-09T21:56:31.630",
    "tenantId": "5566HH"
}
```

I'm looking at building a ticketing system and would like a simple ID field for a user to be sent and who can reference when updating/ searching for.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question, perhaps with a sample document, along with related code. It's unclear what you mean by "simple ID field" - please expand on this.

Comment: Example document added with the ref field showing as an example of a simple identifier which would need to be unique per document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your own purposes, you can choose to either use `id` (which is guaranteed to be unique within a partition) or your own property (such as `ref` as you defined in your example). For any property other than `id`, you'd need to add a unique-key constraint when creating the container (and at that point, `ref` would be unique within any partition, just like `id`).

Really your choice whether you store your custom id's in `id` or `ref`. Just know that, if you ever want to do a direct-read (instead of a query), you can only do a direct-read against an `id`, not against any other property.